# Random value generation from options with chance

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want a way to pick a random element from an array, where the probability of an element being picked is expressed as a percentage on each element.

The array may be in JSON format or a PHP array, though the code has to be written in PHP. The following is an example in JSON:

```
{
    "extreme":  {
        "name":   "item 1",
        "chance": 1.0
    },
    "rare":     {
        "name":   "item 2",
        "chance": 9.0
    },
    "ordinary": {
        "name":   "item 3",
        "chance": 90.0
    }
}
```

For the example above, the following is true:

- `item 1` (`extreme`) should be picked 1 out of 100 times
- `item 2` (`rare`) should be picked 9 out of 100 times
- `item 3` (`ordinary`) should be picked 90 out of 100 times

In simple words: Code for random picking an item from an array or a JSON string, with setting for percentage chance for each item.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You give an example with variables, but we don't really know what they are and how they are determined. Please explain your problem (what you want to do) in more details, and give an example of a result. If would be best if you provide pseudo code of what you want.

Comment: @blex In simple words Random picking an item from an array or a JSON file with setting for percentage chance for each item.

Comment: Ok, could you provide a sample of your JSON, so we can see how these chances are declared?

Comment: `{  
   "extreme":{  
      "name":"item 1",
      "chance":1.0
   },
   "rare":{  
      "name":"item 2",
      "chance":9.0
   },
   "ordinary":{  
      "name":"item 3",
      "chance":90.0
   }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[@mhall's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32040127/1913729) will be faster.**

But I'll leave mine here for the record:

```
<?php

$json_string = '
{ "extreme":{
    "name":"item 1",
    "chance":1.0
  },
  "rare":{
    "name":"item 2",
    "chance":9.0
  },
  "ordinary":{
    "name":"item 3",
    "chance":90.0
  }
}';

$data = json_decode($json_string, true);

$arr = array();

// Cycle through "extreme", "rare" and "ordinary"
foreach($data as $item){
    for($i=0; $i<$item['chance']; $i++){
        // Add the item's name to the array, [chance] times
        array_push($arr, $item['name']);
    }
}

shuffle($arr); // shuffle the array

$chosen_item = $arr[array_rand($arr)]; // Result

echo $chosen_item;

?>
```

I did a test loop, executing it 50,000 times, and got these results:

```
'item 1' => chosen 223 times   (00.4%)
'item 2' => chosen 5133 times  (10.2%)
'item 3' => chosen 44644 times (89.2%)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it:

```
$options = [
    "extreme"  => [
        "name"   => "item 1",
        "chance" => 1.0,
    ],
    "rare"     => [
        "name"   => "item 2",
        "chance" => 9.0,
    ],
    "ordinary" => [
        "name"   => "item 3",
        "chance" => 90.0,
    ]
];

$rand = rand(0, 99);
$max = 0;

foreach ($options as $option) {
    $max += $option['chance'];
    if ($rand < $max) {
        break;
    }
}
echo $option['name'], PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing it this way too :) +1

Comment: using this approach requires the options to be sorted by chance ascending though. Otherwise it won't work properly.